# Eclipse: Constructor call must be the first statement

Tags: java

Why am I getting this error for "this(10)" even if the first statement is a constructor call. I am using eclipse.

```
public class MaxIndependentSet {
    private ArrayList<Integer> inputArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void MaxIndependentSet(int size) {
        inputArr.ensureCapacity(size);
    }

    public void MaxIndependentSet() {
        this(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've added an incorrect return type `void` into your constructor.

The return type of a constructor is its class type, and it is declared implicitly, like so:

```
public MaxIndependentSet() {
    // blah
}
```

Comment: Oops my bad. I wonder how my brain works, deal with java code everyday and still stared at this for a while, yet couldn't notice such a silly thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void MaxIndependentSet() {
        this(10);
    }
```

In your code you added void type but it is a constructor.

Constructors and methods differ in three aspects of the signature: modifiers, return type, and name. Like methods, constructors can have any of the access modifiers: public, protected, private, or none (often called package or friendly). Unlike methods, constructors can take only access modifiers. Therefore, constructors cannot be abstract, final, native, static, or synchronized.

Constructors have no return type, not even void.

just write the code

```
public MaxIndependentSet() {
        this(10);
    }
```

Comment: Constructors internally have a return type--their declaring class.  They also internally do have a method name, `<init>`, rather than the class name as one would expect.

Comment: constructor is to instantiate the class not anything else, it does not have a return type.